# VARCHAR max length is 4000 but only 2666 byte long Thai text can be stored

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with Oracle database 11g with PL/SQL. program is written in C#, .NET 4.

I have a table with a varchar(4000) column, and I want to store in DB a text in Thai language.
I found that when I try to store text in Thai that its length is longer than 1333 Oracle throws an exception, although the maximum length is 4000:

ORA-01461: **can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column**

I also noticed that when I work with smaller limitation it works as expected. i.e.: varchar(10) - allows values in the length of 10 and longer text throws the exception:

ORA-01401 **inserted value too large for column**

From the tests I already made I can assume that from a number 'X' oracle stop counting the actual letter's length. Instead it multiplies the number of letters in the longest letter length value (in Thai the longest letter's length is 3 - meaning it is like 3 chars) and so 1333 * 3 = 3999 and I can only add another one character (in a language like English).

My questions:

1. Why is there a difference in the behavior for a different maximum length?
2. Can I know the real limitation of the text before I try to insert it to the table? (assume that text is in Thai and English and might be also in different languages as well)

**Important note:** Because I need to support a very big and functioning system I can't switch the data type to club but it would solve the problem.

Thanks for your help.

---

**EDIT**

I count the number of bytes of those 1333 characters. their byte length is 2666, which is still, less than 4000. I understand that the max length is in bytes but I don't understand why do I get the exception above.
I used: `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(text)` to check the number of bytes.

Comment: the `4000` means 4000 ***bytes*** not characters. If you are using a multi-byte characterset a character can consist of up to 4 bytes (depending on the character set) There is no way to overcome this limit using a `varchar` column. If you need more, you will need to use a `CLOB` column

Comment: What's your database's NLS_CHARACTERSET set to? Have you considered `NVARCHAR2` columns?

Comment: @Wooble: a `NVARCHAR2` column is also limited to 4000 **bytes**

Comment: the bytes stored in the database for 1333 letters are 2668 - less than 4000. Also, nvarchar has the same problem.

Comment: Hmm; the Oracle documentation seems to indicate that the length you'll be allowed depends on the byte/character semantics, but admittedly I didn't find it 100% clear.

Comment: @hadaco: In what encoding? UTF-8 uses 3 bytes for all of the Thai characters.

Comment: @Wooble has a point - [for some character sets](http://www.micro-isv.asia/2009/03/why-not-use-utf-8-for-everything/), it is more efficient to store data as UTF-16 than it is UTF-8, as certain chars will fit into 2 chars in UTF-16 vs 3 chars in UTF-8, seemingly Thai as well.

Comment: @Wooble: [from the manual for the NVARCHAR2 type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50976): "*The maximum column size allowed is 4000 bytes*"

Comment: @Wooble - we use UTF-8, that might explain that behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The problem

When describing a VARCHAR, you should supply a unit, e.g. `VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)` or `VARCHAR2(200 CHAR)`. If you omit the unit, the default is `BYTE` (see Oracle Database Concepts, chapter [Oracle Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822)). This seems to be like a minor detail, but becomes quite severe, when you have multi byte character sets.

### Situation up to 11g

Unfortunately there is a hard limit on the maximum size of a VARCHAR2 column. It is 4000 BYTEs (!) (see Oracle Database Reference, chapter [Oracle Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903)) up to Oracle 11g and . This is a hard limit and there is no way around this. The only way around this is a CLOB column.

### Solution for 12c

The situation is different on Oracle 12c. There you can use the parameter `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED` to lift the limit up to 32767 BYTEs (see Oracle Database Language Reference, chapter [Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50977) and Oracle Database Reference, chapter [Initialization Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321)). So the obvious solution is: Upgrade to Oracle 12c, set `MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED` [according to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn10321.htm#REFRN10321) and alter your table definition. You might loose some indexes when altering your table, because previously to 12c not indexes could not hold VARCHAR2 values with more than 4000 BYTEs and there might still be some limitation. (I have to check the problem with the indexes and if it can be fixed by rebuilding the indexes).

### Solution: Change database encoding

You could try to change your native database encoding (the way your database maps CHARs to BYTEs). For this you usually have to create a new database and provide an appropriate parameter for NLS_CHARACTERSET. This is a very big change in how your database operates and might have several side effects. If you ever try to add characters in a different encoding, you might be out of luck (i.e. you cannot store them in your database). So I would not suggest this solution.

### Solution: Switch to CLOB

Usually it is not necessary to provide arbitrary queries on such big text fields. You might try to identify the queries selecting on the big text column and migrate them to [Oracle Text](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Text) on a CLOB column. But this is a very big change and might not be possible with your existing schema or your application. You might end up with a bunch of "INSTEAD OF" triggers and with some missing constraint checks (involving the newly created CLOB column).

### Solution: Use XML

Instead of a CLOB you could try to store your string as a XML column. Maximum size for these is 4GB. It will hurt your performance, you will have to provide INSTEAD OF triggers and you might lose some constraints, but it could work for you.

Comment: Note that in Oracle 12c the limit on VARCHAR2 has been raised to 32767 bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Nicely done, but not sure about your statement "indexes cannot hold VARCHAR2 values with more than 4000 BYTEs" - I'm pretty sure they can, 12c would be considered broken otherwise. It's just some functional indexes might become unusable, but they can be fixed.

Comment: OK, I have to check the statement about the indexes on a 12c.

Comment: Indexes over large (>4000 BYTEs) columns are working fine. According to the documentation there can be issues with functional indexes, where you won't be able to get a working index. But I could not reproduce the problem.