# What is the difference between VARCHAR 50 and VARCHAR 50 byte in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently saw a SQL definition where things were written as:

`VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)`

and some as

`VARCHAR2(50)`

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: I personally like the answer here better: [varchar2(n BYTE|CHAR) default -> CHAR or BYTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477564/varchar2n-bytechar-default-char-or-byte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, both of them are the same. Because, by default when you leave out the type it defaults to whatever has been set as the default (which can be either BYTE or CHAR ) . However, you may have specified it as `CHAR` ( you can choose either `BYTE` or `CHAR` ).

For more info - [VARCHAR max length is 4000 but only 2666 byte long Thai text can be stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381354/varchar-max-length-is-4000-but-only-2666-byte-long-thai-text-can-be-stored)

[Oracle data types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm)

[Also see](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_is_the_difference_between_varchar_varchar2_and_char_data_types)

Comment: They are not necessarily the same. If you don't specify the type it depends on session parameter `nls_length_semantics` which defaults to the same system parameter which defaults to BYTE.

Comment: "*when you leave out the type it defaults to BYTE*" - not true. It defaults to whatever is set as the default, which might be byte _or_ char.

Comment: husqvik - do you agree with what @a_horse said ? I feel there's a difference in what i'm hearing

Comment: I essentially said the same as Husqvik. There is also a database parameter that controls that (and the session "inherits" from that)